# TCP Socket between Java(server) and Python(client) on separate machines

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

First of all I want to admit that yes... I am in way over my head with this project and I am just barely scraping by on my limited knowledge of both Python and Java.

GOAL: Use input SocketServer in Java to output data over TCP to Python client on a separate machine.

ISSUE: The code was working perfectly until I moved the Python client to another computer. There are no errors, but the server never prints out the client connected message meaning that the previous line has not been executed.

**JAVA SERVER:**

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class theServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        {
            String godeep;
            int portNumber = 4000;

            String fromclient;

            ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(4000);

            System.out.println("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 5000");

            while (true) {
                Socket connected = Server.accept();

                System.out.println(" THE CLIENT" + " "
                        + connected.getInetAddress() + ":"
                        + connected.getPort() + " IS CONNECTED ");

                DataOutputStream outToPython = new DataOutputStream(
                        connected.getOutputStream());
                while (true) {
                    Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                    godeep= keyboardInput.nextLine();
                    if (godeep.equals("q")) {
                        outToPython.writeBytes("dothatclose");
                        connected.close();
                        break;
                    }
                    outToPython.writeBytes(godeep);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**PYTHON CLIENT:**

```
import Tkinter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SocketServer
import socket
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, False)
GPIO.output(22, False)

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect(("192.168.1.149", 4000))

while 1:
    dumbthing = client_socket.recv(4096)
    if dumbthing == 'dothatclose':
        client_socket.close
        break
    else:
        datInput = raw_input()
    if datInput == 'q':
        GPIO.output(18, True)
        GPIO.output(22, False)

    elif datInput == 'w':
        GPIO.output(18, False)
        GPIO.output(22, True)

    elif datInput == 'p':
        GPIO.output(18, False)
        GPIO.output(22, False)
        break

    else:
        pass
print 'you done brah'
```

This is my first time posting so I am not too familiar with the conventions of what other information to include. Yes I know that my variable names and such are strange but I had so little hope that this would work that I didn't really care all that much. Feel free to give any other suggestions on how to improve my code even if they aren't related to this question because I really don't know what I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: So your python client is connecting to port 4000, but your java serversocket is listening at port 5000?

Comment: Woops, that isn't the issue though sadly. That was something I changed after the fact and forgot to change both values. If you were to try run it like that it would throw an error at you.

Comment: Also, why is your python client receiving at port `4096`? Is there any firewall setting blocking port `4000`?

Comment: That isn't the port it receives at but instead it is the buffsize. The computers are connected to each other over wifi in the same lan. Would firewalls/ portforwarding still be an issue if this is the case?

Comment: Right, my bad about the buffer size. Did your serversocket shows the client is connected? And you started your server before your client?

Comment: The only way I have of knowing if it it connected is through the print statement that only happens if it is connected. Yes I started the server first.

Comment: Attach the wireshark sniff to check whether tcp syn is sent.

Comment: Can you ping the machines running the serve and the client code snippets? Check if both machines can ping each other, perhaps there could be a network problem/misconfiguration. Disable the firewalls and see.

Comment: Yes, I was able to ping both machines from each other. What firewalls do you mean? Like in windows or on the router?